# Change button image on mouse hover

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="WindowBrush" Color="#202020" />
    </Window.Background>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/button.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/button-hover.png"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="285*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="349*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="21,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And of course, I have two images im my project — `button.png` and `button-hover.png`.
But when cursor is over my button it apply default Windows style, not my `button-hover.png` image.
Where is my mistake?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mouseOverBackgroundImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="pressedBackgroundImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Image Name="normalBackgroundImage" Source="{TemplateBinding local:BackgroundImages.NormalBackgroundImage}"/>
                <Image Name="mouseOverBackgroundImage" Source="{TemplateBinding local:BackgroundImages.MouseOverBackgroundImage}" Opacity="0"/>
                <Image Name="pressedBackgroundImage" Source="{TemplateBinding local:BackgroundImages.PressedBackgroundImage}" Opacity="0"/>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

used in a Button with the attached properties set:

```
<Button local:BackgroundImages.NormalBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg"
    local:BackgroundImages.MouseOverBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
    local:BackgroundImages.PressedBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg"
    Content="Hello"/>
```

And finally the definition of those attached properties:

```
public static class BackgroundImages
{
public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalBackgroundImageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NormalBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(BackgroundImages));

public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseOverBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(BackgroundImages));

public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedBackgroundImageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PressedBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(BackgroundImages));

public static ImageSource GetNormalBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(NormalBackgroundImageProperty);
}

public static void SetNormalBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
{
    obj.SetValue(NormalBackgroundImageProperty, value);
}

public static ImageSource GetMouseOverBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty);
}

public static void SetMouseOverBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
{
    obj.SetValue(MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty, value);
}

public static ImageSource GetPressedBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(PressedBackgroundImageProperty);
}

public static void SetPressedBackgroundImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
{
    obj.SetValue(PressedBackgroundImageProperty, value);
}
}
```

For triggers, Try something like this. I'm not sure of this: (just add the image to an /Images folder in the project)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
<Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" 
            Background="Transparent">
      <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyProjectName;component/Images/MyImage.jpg" />
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

You could define attached properties for the background images for states Normal, MouseOver and Pressed (and maybe more). You would use these attached properties for the Sourceproperty of separate Image controls in a control template and modify e.g. the Image's Opacity when the VisualState changes.

Comment: Sure it could be done only in XAML. But first you have to answer one question, at least if you want to use the `VisualStateManager`. Are you using .Net 4 or higher? [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the reason.

Comment: @WasimAbu-Nassar Ok, great. I'm only descibing it, because I hope that **ling.s** will provide an illustration. You could use multiple `Images` overlapping each other but only one is visible while the other(s) are invisible. This could easily achieved by changing the `Opacity` from 0 to 1 and vice versa.

Comment: You forgot add code for change opacity for normal background to 0 if button pressed or hovered. Without this exists bug with mixing images. Anyway thanks. Only this code 100% works w/o bugs with 3 images for button.